# recurring_select gem: jquery not working in my configuration

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, cdn

I'm trying to use recurring_select on a rails 5 project to select recurring dates for events.  Everything seems to work except for the jquery modal popup.  I suspect it has something to do with the way I've configured the asset pipeline in my project, because when I test recurring_select in a brand new single model scaffolded project, it works. But it won't work in my "real" project.  The differences in my asset pipeline approach for the "real" project include:
- using CDN link for Jquery (as shown on the bootstrap 4 startup guide), not including require statements for jquery in application.js 
- not including require_tree in application.js and application.css, instead specifying:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

in my application.html.erb file.

Any guidance is much appreciated by this newbie.  Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Rafiki</title>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<!--       <%= link_to image_tag("lion_small.png", alt: "Brand"), root_path, :class=>'navbar-brand' %> -->
<%= link_to image_tag('https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cryptic-garden-assets/images/lion_small.png', alt: "Brand"), root_path, :class=>'navbar-brand' %>



      <% if user_signed_in? %><%= current_user.email %> |
        <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path %> |
        <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
        <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> | 
      <% end %>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">

         <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Encounters
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <%= link_to "Today", encounters_today_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "This Week", encounters_by_week_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "This Month", encounters_by_month_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "Provider Hours", new_provider_hour_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Maintenance
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <%= link_to "New Encounter", new_encounter_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "encounters", encounters_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "participants", participants_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "services", services_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "payment sources", payment_sources_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "rates", rates_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "auth_hours", auth_hours_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "goals", goals_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "users", users_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
              <%= link_to "provider hours", provider_hours_path, class: "dropdown-item" %>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <% if notice %>
      <p class="alert alert-success"><%= notice %></p>
    <% end %>
    <% if alert %>
      <p class="alert alert-danger"><%= alert %></p>
    <% end %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The select_recurring method is used in a "new encounter" form as shown below:

```
<h1>New Encounter</h1>

<%= bootstrap_form_with(model: @encounter, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if @encounter.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@encounter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this encounter from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @encounter.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.collection_select(:participant_id, Participant.all, :id, :name_with_initial, {prompt: 'Select Participant'}, {required: true}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.radio_button :encounter_type, 'work', required: true %> 
    <%= form.radio_button :encounter_type, 'group', required: true %>
    <%= form.radio_button :encounter_type, 'other', required: true %>
  </div>
  </br>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.collection_check_boxes :service_ids, Service.all, :id, :name, checked: @encounter.service_ids %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.date_field(:encounter_date, :value => form.object.encounter_date || Date.current) %>
    <%= form.select_recurring :recurring, nil, allow_blank: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_field(:duration_hours, :value => form.object.duration_hours || 3.0) %>
  </div>

   <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :work_goal_assessment do |assessment| %>
      <%= assessment.collection_select(:goal_id, Goal.where(category: "Work"), :id, :name, label: "Work Goal", prompt: 'Select Work Goal',  disabled: !current_user.admin?) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :social_goal_assessment do |assessment| %>
      <%= assessment.collection_select(:goal_id, Goal.where(category: "Social"), :id, :name, label: "Social Goal", prompt: 'Select Social Goal', disabled: !current_user.admin?) %>

    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.fields_for :community_goal_assessment do |assessment| %>
      <%= assessment.collection_select(:goal_id, Goal.where(category: "Community"), :id, :name, label: "Community Goal", prompt: 'Select Community Goal', disabled: !current_user.admin?) %>

    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', encounters_path %>
```

I wondered about putting the CDN script references at the bottom of the  tag but that's where bootstrap said to put it in their docs.  Just for grins, I shifted  it to ABOVE the "yield" statement in application.html.erb but that didn't do anything.  I also put it at the top of the  section and that didn't help either.  Still getting the same error.  I also swapped out the CDN source to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js and that didn't help.  Thank you for looking at this!

Comment: Did you add recurring_select js in your application.js? Also check the browser console, you should se errors and more info.

Comment: Thanks!  I did add recurring_select.  Here's the error from the browser console:  Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at recurring_select.self.js?body=1:4
    at recurring_select.self.js?body=1:116

Comment: I wonder if it's because I'm using the slim.min.js version: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: I guess recurring_select is getting excecuted before jquery is actually loaded. Show where you use it, I suppose you are not wrapping that inside a jquery document ready event.

Comment: Thanks.  I attached the view where select_recurring method is used.  What's odd is that I'm including it in a view exactly as I did in my single-model test project. big difference is that jquery comes from the jquery-rails gem in my test project, but from CDN in my "real" project.

Comment: You can try moving the `javascript_include_tag` after jquery's tag, or use jquery from the assets pipeline instead of a CDN (personally I prefer to use just the asset pipeline since it can be minified and compressed with the rest of the code and rails manages cache really good with the precompilation and digest)

Comment: moving the javascript_include_tag worked!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arieljuod provided the answer in a comment.  I needed to make sure that the <% javascript_include_tag 'application' %> came AFTER the script that loads jquery.